# BLE scan and communication in c++

Tags: c++, uwp, bluetooth, mfc, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently trying to implement a BLE scanning function for a Windows 10 application.

It's an old software based on a c++ / MFC solution.

This software is now using a bluegiga dongle (viewed as a COM port).
All bluetooth accesses are done using a dll that is loaded at the start-up.
I want to avoid the dongle and switch to the windows drivers.

I explored these paths :

- the Bluetoothleapis.h library : I can't make it work on my computer... And all the examples I found on the internet are not working.
- I used Qt because some are saying that this is the current way to go. The example is really easy to use and is working as expected. But merging Qt in my project would be a nightmare (+ some legal issues). => it can't be used as is.
- I tried WinRT libraries in a UWP application (based on the microsoft examples found on github here : https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE
  Once again, the example is working as expected, and is easy to understand. But, I really don't know how to integrate this into my soft. I tried to create a simple UWP dll: it compiles and everything seems fine, but when it is loaded at the start-up, it crashes... "error while loading the dll"

So, here are my questions :

- Based my current situation, is there a clear solution ?
- Did I forgot any other possibility ?
- If the WinRT/UWP path is correct, is it possible to use a dll and include it into my ancient project ?
- Or, do I need to restructure the whole project ? (It can be done, but is tidious because of the inspection process... )

I am in no way an expert in these fields, so any help would be really appreciated !

From a lost dev,
Thank you.

Comment: The Windows Runtime and UWP are not the same thing. The latter encompasses a set of APIs exposed using the former. There is no technical limitation using the vast majority of Windows Runtime types in a classic Windows desktop application. As long as you are meeting the minimum system requirements.

Comment: You have to use WinRT (UWP) API. Or use third party libraries. We have one: https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for this clarification ! I will retry it.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I will use winrt, thanks. I saw your website, and I will evaluate the possibility.